# Snowflake - Difference between Merge Into , Copy Into, Insert into?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Pretty much like the title asks, what is the difference between `Merge Into` , `Copy Into`, `Insert into`? and when is a good time to use either?

I've used `Copy Into` to insert a file from s3 to Snowflake, but I haven't found a doc on when is the best time to use either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage could be divided into:

```
INSERT INTO - insert rows

INSERT OVERWRITE INTO - truncate table and insert rows 

MERGE INTO - upsert, insert/update/delete

COPY INTO - load data from stage into table/unload data
```

Details could be found in the docs for [copy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table), [insert](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert), and [merge](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge).

Comment: Thanks! so can I use use Merge and Insert interchangeably?

Comment: @KristiLuna Yes, it is possible to use MERGE to INSERT only, though that syntax would be "overkill". On the other hand INSERT cannot Update/delete values